# Data structures : Lists and Arrays

Tags: data-structures

If in `Lists`, data is stored in random memory locations with a pointer to the next location, how can we read the lists easily with an index?

In `Array`, it is a continuous chunk of memory so indexing is possible.

I read that reading from an array is efficient than reading from a list. 
I'm confused.
I'm particularly concerned with Python.

Comment: Indexing in the linked list data structure is `O(n)`: you should start from the first element of the list and iterate till the desired index.

Comment: But I got an answer that in python lists are stored as dynamic arrays. Which one is right ?

Comment: `list` in python is implemented as a dynamic array, not linked list. Don't confuse abstract data type list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type) with linked list data structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list